# How can I decrypt ciphertext from openssl aes-256 using an RSA keyfile

Tags: openssl, aes

I'm devising an encryption scheme to send files to an embedded device. Developers can log in via a shared public key, so it makes sense to use this same key to encrypt/decrypt files sent to it. Files are only packaged by the developers, so this public key is never given out.

The files sent only need to be secure enough to make it difficult to decrypt, not anything NSA quality or anything.

I can encrypt/decrypt using something like this:

```
cat file | openssl [-d] aes-256-cbc -kfile path/to/public/key > outfile.aes
```

This is working great, except that I'd like to do this in the server code. I can shell out, but I'd rather do it in code.

I grabbed the base64 data from the key, but when I decode it, I get a 279 byte array, but I need a 256-bit key (32 bytes).

What exactly does openssl do with the keyfile and how can I emulate it in code?

I tried `man openssl`, but I didn't find anything useful.

If it matters, I'm doing this in Go.

Comment: You want to use an RSA *public* key as an AES key? And if you don't give the public key out, how will the device decrypt the files?

Comment: The device has the public key (the same one developers log in with).

Comment: So anyone with access to the device has access to the public key. If you use the public key to encrypt/decrypt the file, anyone with access to the device can encrypted and decrypt files. Why are you trying to prevent people from decrypting the file? Are its contents secret? If so, from whom?

Comment: I think it's mostly to keep honest people honest. We'd really rather our clients not be able to easily decrypt the file, since it contains some intellectual property. Since they have physical access, it won't be completely secure anyway. They don't have access to the public key without opening our sealed box, so I thought this was a decent enough solution to the problem. The packages are mostly compiled binaries, so we're not risking any source or anything like that.

Comment: "Developers can log in via a shared **public** key" does really not make any sense to me. Public keys are not used for logging in, **private** keys are. Private keys may be shared between developers, but normally you simply give each one a key and use PKI (e.g. certificate chains) to give them access to the same device.

Comment: @owlstead - We just add the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. I'm pretty sure the private key is not used for logging in (handshaking) at all with that setup. The private key is shared as well. All in all, not too secure, but it's good enough.

Comment: Still, you should use the private key as import. The reason that you add the public key to the authorized_keys file on the server is to establish trust; the *private* keys signature is now trusted to authorize the client to log in. It's normally only the private key that is protected against sharing (e.g. by hiding it behind a passphrase, using password based encryption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL uses a specific key derivation function to calculate the key from the "password" it is given. This function is called `EVP_BytesToKey`. It is part of the OpenSSL API, so if you can call C/C++ functions you could use it directly. Otherwise there are also other implementations available (and it is actually not that hard to implement, I created an object oriented Java version of it).

I'll let you do the stackoverflow searches for this algorithm yourself, if you don't mind :)